# Setting the default app to open .vid files to be VLC

Tags: windows-10, vlc-media-player

I am trying to set VLC to be the default app that opens a .vid file. However when I right-click on 'Open with' the window does not suggest any apps to open with. When I click on 'more apps' the list of suggested apps does not contain VLC (VLC is on my computer by the way, I know because it is the default app for all the recognised video filetypes). When I click on 'look for other apps in this PC' it opens up the 'Program Files' folder but I cannot see VLC on the list.

**Does anyone know where the VLC application is stored on my computer so I can set it to be the default for .vid files?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know where the VLC application is stored on my computer so I can set it to be the default for .vid files?

Go to

```
C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC
```

then click on VLC.exe

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the @TamalesRancheros but there is no folder named VideoLAN visible. I suspect some of my applications are hidden, there are so few listed.

Comment: What about `C:\Program Files (x86)`?

Comment: Nope, the last folder is WinZip. Something's up.

Comment: Why don't you try a reinstall of vlc

Comment: Once it's installed again, try right click on the VLC icon on your desktop then click open file location

Comment: Actually that worked. I went one level back in the filepath to x 'Windows (C:)' and then found 'Program Files (x86)', which *did* have the 'VideoLAN' folder in it. Sorry for being a bit slow. So what is 'Program Files (x86)' and how is it different from 'Program Files'?

Comment: No worries, about the difference between program files and the x86, it's a little bit long to answer here but you can check it out quickly here: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Program-Files-and-Program-Files-x86  Have a good night !